# beforeEach in Jest timing out when clearing db

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to clear the dynamic tables in my db in typeorm between each test, so i have this clear function:

```
const database  = {

  async create() {
    await createConnection();
  },

async clear() {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Clear database...");
      const dynamicEntities = [
          EntityOne,
          EntityTwo,
          EntityThree
      ];

      try{// iterate over dynamic entities and clean all their tables
        
        for (let entity of dynamicEntities) {
          // get entity repository
          const repository = getRepository(entity);
          // delete all rows
          await repository.delete({});
        }
        resolve("Successfully clear database!!!");
      }catch(err){
        reject(err);
      }
    })
},
};
```

It works fine when i use it with beforeAll or afterAll, but it times out when there is more than one describe(), and i need a couple of describes for my testing.

I need to make this work:

```
describe("testing jest", () => {

beforeAll(async () => {
  await database.create();
});

  afterEach(async() => {
    await database.clear();
});

  describe("test 1", () => {
    it("should return 200", () => {
        expect(100+100).toBe(200)
    });
  });

  describe("test 2", () => {
    it("should return 100", () => {
      expect(50+50).toBe(100)
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: [afterEach and other startup/teardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#aftereachfn-timeout) functions has timeout argument 
`afterEach(async() => { await database.clear(); }, 10000);`
And try to [truncate table](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_repository_.repository.html#clear)
`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it, i was also disabling fk checks inside my clear() func **for** loop and re enabling it later , but when i moved it outside the loop it worked and the beforeEach no longer times out

```
try{// iterate over dynamic entities and clean all their tables
        await getConnection().createQueryRunner().query(`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`);
        for (let entity of dynamicEntities) {

            // get entity repository
            const repository = getRepository(entity);
            // delete all rows
            await repository.delete({});
        }
        await getConnection().createQueryRunner().query(`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`);
        resolve("Successfully clear database!!!");
      }catch(err){
        await getConnection().createQueryRunner().query(`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`);
        reject(err);
      }
```

Comment: Update: Since i was running multiple test suites using this function, i needed to run them sequentially (--runInBand), otherwise sometimes the db wasn't cleared or the dummy data wasn't dumped in time